# Unable to parse template language expression 'encodeURIComponent([parameters('table_storage_name')])'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

Hey I am doing a CI/CD deployment for a logic app, I have a table storage where I store some data, I have two table storage for **test** and **prod** environment. I created a parameter called *table_storage_name" in ARM template :

```json
"parameters": {
// ....
"connections_azuretables_1_externalid": {
   "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/e5..../resourceGroups/myrg.../providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuretables-1",
      "type": "String"
        },
"table_storage_name": {
          "defaultValue": "testdevops",
          "type": "String"
        }
}
```

The error comes from when I reference the parameter here in *template.json* file:

```json
// ...
"Insert_Entity": {
  "runAfter": {
      "Initialize_variable": [
          "Succeeded"
      ]
  },
  "type": "ApiConnection",
  "inputs": {
      "body": {
          "PartitionKey": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['name']",
          "RowKey": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['last']"
      },
      "host": {
          "connection": {
              "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azuretables_1']['connectionId']"
          }
      },
      "method": "post",
      // problem occur after this line
      "path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent('[parameters('table_storage_name')]')}/entities"
  }
}
```

but get this error:

> InvalidTemplate: The template validation failed: 'The template action 'Insert_Entity' at line '1' and column '582' is not valid: "Unable to parse template language expression 'encodeURIComponent([parameters('table_storage_name')])': expected token 'Identifier' and actual 'LeftSquareBracket'.".'.

I tried escaping the quote with a backslash like: `encodeURIComponent(\'[parameters('table_storage_name')]\')` or `encodeURIComponent('[parameters(''table_storage_name'')]')` but all of them raise an error. How can I reference a paramter inside encodeURIComponent in an ARM template ?

Comment: can you show a bit more context from your ARM template around the two lines you showed?

Comment: see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution from this link https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd

but here are the steps to reference a parameter logic app:

1. create an ARM parameter **table_storage_name_armparam** in template.json, in order to use it's value to reference the value of the ARM parameter (yes it's confusing but follow along you'll understand):

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "table_storage_name_armparam": {
          "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
         ......
}
```

2. Now in the logic app parameter value (in the bottom of json file) create the logic app parameter **table_storage_name** and the value of this parameter will be the ARM parameter created in step 1:

```json
.......
"parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                        "value": {
                            "azuretables": {
                                "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_azuretables_externalid')]",
                                "connectionName": "azuretables",
                                "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/francecentral/managedApis/azuretables"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "table_storage_name": {
                      "value": "[parameters('table_storage_name_armparam')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

3. finally, reference the logic app parameter value as follow:

```json
"path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent(parameters('table_storage_name'))}/entities"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: I could use help, in Step 2 I got in an error when trying to use the parameters, "The workflow parameters are not valid, The only declared parameters for this definition are '$connections'". I have no idea how to solve this, I honestly did not understand this answer enitrely

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments. credits: @marone

```
 "path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent(parameters('table_storage_name'))}/entities"
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, it's working but we got a new error :) `"Unable to parse template language expression 'encodeURIComponent(testdevopsprod)': expected token 'LeftParenthesis' and actual 'RightParenthesis'.".'` it must be `encodeURIComponent('testdevopsprod')` with quotes I guess no ?

Comment: I tried this `"/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(parameters('table_storage_name')))}/entities"` from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275479/logic-app-deployment-from-dev-to-prod) but got an error in logic app when inserting an entity: `Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Insert_Entity' inputs at line '1' and column '1962': 'The workflow parameter 'table_storage_name' is not found.'` I checked the paramter file after deployment in **prod** but didn't found **table_storage_name** parameter and template.json I created it

Comment: this one worked `"path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent(parameters('table_storage_name'))}/entities"`

Comment: @marone Thanks for your sharing, you could post your answer and mark it as accepted answer, which will help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: @marOne I changed my answer. Feel free to post your own and I'll delete mine or accept my answer.

Comment: @silent just delete my credits ^^ I found the complete solution in this link https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd, the value of logic app parameter is referenced by an ARM parameter. I will add a more detailed answer soon.